# Azure Blob Storage - Retrieve user that reads or writes blob in Storage Container

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a question regarding Blob Storage: how to know the AD user that writes or reads a blob file in a container. I cannot see the property at blob level, neither in Storage Account Activity Log (at least for a specific blob file).

Is there a way to know, for each blob in my container, which user has accessed it and how it dealt with the blob?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: was the provided answer helpful to you ? If so please upvote or mark as answer to help the community which may ask a similar question in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not an option in the current logs that are generated, they aren't fine grained yet(will be better on a newer release). the current log format would only indicate whether the request was authenticated or not,

This is an example of logs 2.0 for azure storage:

```
1.0;2014-06-19T01:33:54.0926521Z;PutBlob;Success;201;197;54;authenticated;storagesample;storagesample;blob;"https://storagesample.blob.core.windows.net/sample-container1/00001.txt";"/storagesample/sample-container1/00001.txt";a200be85-1c98-4dd9-918e-f13d8c0538e0;0;192.100.0.102:4362;2014-02-14;460;23;225;0;23;"DrPO6z1f00SCsomhaf+J/A==";"DrPO6z1f00SCsomhaf+J/A==";""0x8D15975AA456EA4"";Thursday, 19-Jun-14 01:33:53 GMT;;"WA-Storage/4.0.1 (.NET CLR 4.0.30319.34014; Win32NT 6.3.9600.0)";;"1fe6814a-e4cb-4195-a3cf-837dc7120f68"
```

It only shows whether it's an authenticated request or not, but not specifically which User accessed which blob.The full format of logs can be viewed [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Storage-Analytics-Log-Format)